# How do I make navigation bar buttons show and hide divs/sections on click without javascript or JQuery?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am coding a page for an assignment and there are three sections in the navbar: Business Plan, About Us and Contact Us. I have the navbar from a codepen, and I was learning about label and radio input to have clickable buttons that will show and hide elements when you click them. However, since I'm still learning, I'm having a hard time making the navbar buttons work with that function while keeping the CSS styling

How do I do that? What am I fundamentally doing wrong?

This is the code that I have. I was trying to have the buttons within  to have that function, but if I try to place my divs in there it fundamentally breaks the layout (it populates the business plan section inside the header-navigation)

This is the closest that I got to what I wanted, but I end up having two navbars and the one that has the visual styling that I want isn't the one that actually works

Example: if I click Plano de Negócios, I want to see "Missão...", "Ameaças..." and the other elements ([example](https://i.imgur.com/5QERbyy.png))

If I click Localização, I want this to show up ([example](https://i.imgur.com/XUkcUnj.png))

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TIME Design de Serviço</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles2.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="banner-outer">
        <div class="banner-inner responsive-wrapper">
            <!-- Placeholder logo in SVG format -->
            <div class="logo-wrapper">
                <div class="white-square"></div>
                <div class="pastel-square"></div>
                <img src="logo.svg" class="logo fade-out" alt="Company Logo">
            </div>
            <!-- End of placeholder logo -->
        </div>
    </div>
<header class="header-outer">
    <div class="header-inner responsive-wrapper">
        <div class="header-logo">
            <img src="logo2.svg" />
        </div>
        <nav class="header-navigation">
            <a href="#">Plano de Negócios</a>
            <a href="#">Localização</a>
            <a href="#">Contato</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>


    <main>
<nav class="header-navigation">
    <label class="collapse" for="about-us">Sobre nós</label>
    <input id="about-us" type="radio" name="navigation" checked>
    <div class="about-us-section">
        <!-- Content for "About Us" section with Google Maps map -->
        <!-- Replace this with your Google Maps embed code -->
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d248789.81007519642!2d-0.24168169117477634!3d51.52877184119049!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487604e9773e46e5%3A0x52963a5addd52a99!2sLondon%2C%20UK!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1647455567883!5m2!1sen!2suk" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
    </div>

    <label class="collapse" for="contact-us">Contato</label>
    <input id="contact-us" type="radio" name="navigation">
    <div class="contact-us-section">
        <!-- Content for "Contact Us" section with contact information and "Join Us" ad block -->
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Contato</h2>
            <div class="contact-info">
                <p><strong>Endereço:</strong> Rua Exemplo, 1234 - Cidade, Estado</p>
                <p><strong>Telefone:</strong> (123) 456-7890</p>
                <p><strong>Email:</strong> info@exemplo.com</p>
            </div>
            <div class="join-us">
                <h3>Junte-se a nós!</h3>
                <p>Estamos sempre em busca de talentos. Envie seu currículo para careers@exemplo.com.</p>
                <!-- Replace this with your "Join Us" ad block content -->
                <img src="join-us-image.jpg" alt="Join Us Image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <label class="collapse" for="business-plan">Plano de Negócios</label>
    <input id="business-plan" type="radio" name="navigation">
    <div class="business-plan-section">
        <section id="missao" class="section missao">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Missão e Objetivos Estratégicos</h2>
                <p>A missão da TIME Design de Serviço é revitalizar a estrutura e a qualidade dos serviços prestados por empresas na região, melhorando as relações e a satisfação dos clientes e do ambiente de trabalho. Nossos objetivos estratégicos incluem a otimização do fluxo de informação, aprimoramento da experiência do usuário e a criação de um ambiente de trabalho mais positivo e produtivo.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="ameacas_oportunidades" class="section ameacas">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Ameaças e Oportunidades</h2>
                <p>As ameaças incluem a resistência das empresas conservadoras à mudança e a concorrência de outras empresas de consultoria. No entanto, as oportunidades são vastas, pois muitas empresas estão buscando melhorias em seus processos e estão abertas a novas abordagens que possam otimizar seus negócios, aumentar sua competitividade e oferecer soluções inovadoras e personalizadas para as necessidades específicas de cada cliente.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="pontos_fortes" class="section pontosfortes">
            <div class="content">
            <h2>Pontos Fortes</h2>
            <p>A TIME Design de Serviço destaca-se pela sua abordagem centrada no cliente e na melhoria da experiência do usuário, além da expertise de sua equipe em identificar e implementar soluções eficazes para otimizar os processos de trabalho das empresas com análise detalhada dos processos, prototipagem rápida e estratégias de melhoria do ambiente de trabalho.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <section id="pontos_fracos" class="section pontosfracos">
            <div class="content">
            <h2>Pontos Fracos</h2>
            <p>Os pontos fracos incluem a necessidade de enfrentar a resistência à mudança por parte de algumas empresas e a dependência da economia regional, a possibilidade da dependência de um modelo de negócios baseado em consultoria poder limitar a capacidade de escalar rapidamente, e a possibilidade da empresa enfrentar desafios para atrair clientes em um mercado competitivo.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <section id="descricao_produto" class="section descricao">
            <div class="content">
            <h2>Descrição do Produto/Serviço</h2>
            <p>O serviço que a empresa oferece é uma melhoria na estrutura de trabalho das empresas, otimizando o fluxo de informações e melhorando a experiência do usuário, não só dos clientes da empresa, por meio de melhorias na qualidade do serviço prestado, mas também melhorando a experiência do usuário que trabalha na empresa, tornando-a um lugar melhor para se trabalhar. Um período de imersão é feito pelos pesquisadores da TIME na empresa que está sendo estudada, onde cada processo de trabalho e tarefa é entendido e analisado para ver áreas de melhoria, sistemas, fluxogramas, planilhas que podem ser desenvolvidos para eles pela TIME, ciclos de informação que podem ser automatizados e assim economizar minutos, até horas e dias de trabalho. Durante essa imersão, a TIME também oferece Happy Hours para obter noções acerca das dinâmicas sociais dos funcionários, bem como para inicializar processos de melhorias na atmosfera emocional do local de trabalho.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <section id="foco_negocio" class="section foco">
            <div class="content">
            <h2>Foco do Negócio</h2>
            <p>O foco da TIME Design de Serviço está em ajudar empresas de serviços a otimizar suas operações, melhorar a satisfação do cliente e criar um ambiente de trabalho mais positivo e produtivo para seus funcionários. Empresas de comércio podem ter suas operações otimizadas, mas empresas de prestação de serviços podem se beneficiar mais diretamente da carga horária de trabalho reduzida.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <section id="diferenciais_produtos" class="section diferenciais">
            <div class="content">
            <h2>Diferenciais dos Produtos/Serviços</h2>
            <p>Nosso diferencial está na combinação de consultoria especializada em serviço com intervenções práticas e expertise técnica em design de serviço, com imersão detalhada nas empresas-cliente, prototipagem rápida e eventos de integração, e a oferta de soluções personalizadas e inovadoras para atender às necessidades específicas de cada cliente.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <section id="estrategias_venda" class="section estrategias">
            <div class="content">
            <h2>Estratégias de Venda/Marketing</h2>
            <p>As estratégias de venda e marketing da TIME Design de Serviço serão conduzidas principalmente por meio das redes sociais e visitas direcionadas às empresas-alvo. Ofereceremos uma consulta gratuita, pesquisa e happy hour, onde a TIME desenvolverá um protótipo de solução para os desafios imediatos enfrentados pela empresa em seu pipeline de execução. Isso nos permite demonstrar o valor de nossos serviços e conquistar a confiança das empresas interessadas em melhorar suas operações.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</nav>



    </main>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <p>&copy; 2024 TIME Design de Serviço. Todos os direitos reservados.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

styles.css:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f9f7f0;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

header {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.logo {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 -156px;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 330px;
  filter: invert(4%) sepia(44%) saturate(3197%) hue-rotate(239deg) brightness(89%) contrast(92%);
}

.subtitle {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #d4a255;
}

main {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.section {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    color: #333333;
}

.section:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 199, 95, 0.7), rgba(255, 199, 95, 255));
}


.content {
  padding: 40px 40px 25px 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 350px;
  /*! display: flex; */
}

h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    /*! text-align: center; */
    /*! min-width: 532px; */
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
    /*! margin: -9px; */
    margin-block-start: 101px;
    /*! margin-block-end: -21px; */
    /*! align-content: end; */
    /*! align-self: end; */
    /*! display: flex; */
    align-self: flex-end;
}

footer {
    background-color: #f9f7f0;
    padding: 20px 0;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: center;
}

footer p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}


/* Background images for each section */
.missao {
    background-image: url('missao.webp'); /* Placeholder address for Missão section */
}

.ameacas {
    background-image: url('ameacas.webp'); 
background-position-y: -200px;
}

.pontosfortes {
  background-image: url('pontosfortes.jpeg');
  background-position-y: -121px;
  background-position-x: 81px;
}

.pontosfracos {
    background-image: url('pontosfracos.webp'); 
background-position-y: -126px
}

.descricao {
    background-image: url('descricao.webp'); 
background-position-y: -174px;
}

.foco {
    background-image: url('foco.webp'); 
background-position-y: -37px;
}

.diferenciais {
    background-image: url('diferenciais.webp'); 
background-position-y: -37px;
}

.estrategias {
    background-image: url('estrategias.jpeg'); 
background-position-y: -348px;
}

/* Add more section classes with background images as needed */

.logo-wrapper {
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s forwards;
}

.logo-wrapper.fade-out {
    animation: fadeOut 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

/* Detect scroll event and apply fade-out animation */
body.scrolled-down .logo-wrapper {
    animation: fadeOut 0.5s forwards;
}



@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.white-square {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -79px;
  left: 23px;
  width: 76%;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.fade-out .white-square {
    opacity: 0;
}

.pastel-square {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 24%;
  height: 135px;
  background-color: #fdc8b0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  bottom: -33px;
}

.fade-out .white-square {
    opacity: 0;
}

.logobox {
    position: relative;
}

.collapse {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.collapse + input {
    display: none; /* hide the radio inputs */
}

.collapse + input + div {
    display: none;
}

.collapse + input:checked + div {
    display: block;
}

/* Additional styling for each section */
.about-us-section,
.contact-us-section,
.business-plan-section {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

styles2.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');

*,
*:after,
*:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    /* Banner */
    --banner-outer-height: 100vh;
    --banner-inner-height: 5vh;
    --banner-height-difference: calc(
        var(--banner-outer-height) - var(--banner-inner-height)
    );
    --banner-bg: #ffc75f;
    
    /* Header */
    --header-outer-height: 110px;
    --header-inner-height: 70px;
    --header-bg: #FFF;
}

body {
    font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
    background-color: #f2f5f7;
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 300vh;
    position: relative;
}


a {
    color: inherit;
}

.responsive-wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* Sticky banner */
.banner-outer {
    /* Make it stick */
    height: var(--banner-outer-height);
    position: sticky;
    top: calc(var(--banner-height-difference) * -1); /* Multiply by -1 to get a negative value */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
    /* Other */ 
    background-color: var(--banner-bg);
    z-index: 2;
        background-image: url(headerbackground.jpg);
        background-size: 144%;
        background-position-x: -151px;
}

.banner-outer:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 199, 95, 0.5), rgba(255, 199, 95, 255));
}

.banner-inner {
    /* Make it stick */
    height: var(--banner-inner-height);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    
    /* Other */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.25;
    z-index: 2;
}

.header-outer {
  height: 15vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--header-bg);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0, .1);
  top: 5vh;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 2
}


.header-inner {
    height: var(--header-inner-height); 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Styling of other elements */
.header-logo img {
    display: block;
    height: calc(var(--header-inner-height) + 20px);
}

.header-navigation {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header-navigation a,
.header-navigation button {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: 1.75rem;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.header-navigation a {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header-navigation button {
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
}

.header-navigation a:hover:after,
.header-navigation button:hover:after {
    transform: scalex(1);
}

.header-navigation a:after,
.header-navigation button:after {
    transition: 0.25s ease;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: currentcolor;
    transform: scalex(0);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
}

.main {
    margin-top: 3rem;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .header-navigation a {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .header-navgitaion button {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to click on an item in the nav bar and have a drop down menu appear, correct?

Comment: No, I don't want a drop-down menu. I want to click an item on the nav bar and change the elements that are being displayed.

Example: if I click Plano de Negócios, I want to see "Missão...", "Ameaças..." and the other elements ([example](https://i.imgur.com/5QERbyy.png))

If I click Localização, I want this to show up ([example](https://i.imgur.com/XUkcUnj.png))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for that the :has() selector in css .header-navigation:has(#about-us:checked) #missao to select the section with id=missao content if the checkbox with id=about-us is checked and then display it to none as an example. In this example when checking the #about-us checkbox the section content with id #missao is displayed to none (same for checkbox business-plan and section with id#ameacas_oportunidades). Check code snippet full page and you will see. (NB I also removed the default attribute 'checked' in about us input )

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');

*,
*:after,
*:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    /* Banner */
    --banner-outer-height: 100vh;
    --banner-inner-height: 5vh;
    --banner-height-difference: calc(
        var(--banner-outer-height) - var(--banner-inner-height)
    );
    --banner-bg: #ffc75f;
    
    /* Header */
    --header-outer-height: 110px;
    --header-inner-height: 70px;
    --header-bg: #FFF;
}

body {
    font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
    background-color: #f2f5f7;
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 300vh;
    position: relative;
}


a {
    color: inherit;
}

.responsive-wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* Sticky banner */
.banner-outer {
    /* Make it stick */
    height: var(--banner-outer-height);
    position: sticky;
    top: calc(var(--banner-height-difference) * -1); /* Multiply by -1 to get a negative value */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
    /* Other */ 
    background-color: var(--banner-bg);
    z-index: 2;
        background-image: url(headerbackground.jpg);
        background-size: 144%;
        background-position-x: -151px;
}

.banner-outer:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 199, 95, 0.5), rgba(255, 199, 95, 255));
}

.banner-inner {
    /* Make it stick */
    height: var(--banner-inner-height);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    
    /* Other */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.25;
    z-index: 2;
}

.header-outer {
  height: 15vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--header-bg);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0, .1);
  top: 5vh;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 2
}


.header-inner {
    height: var(--header-inner-height); 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Styling of other elements */
.header-logo img {
    display: block;
    height: calc(var(--header-inner-height) + 20px);
}

.header-navigation {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header-navigation a,
.header-navigation button {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: 1.75rem;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.header-navigation a {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header-navigation button {
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
}

.header-navigation a:hover:after,
.header-navigation button:hover:after {
    transform: scalex(1);
}

.header-navigation a:after,
.header-navigation button:after {
    transition: 0.25s ease;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: currentcolor;
    transform: scalex(0);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
}

.main {
    margin-top: 3rem;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .header-navigation a {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .header-navgitaion button {
        display: none;
    }
}

.header-navigation:has(#about-us:checked) #missao{ /*this is the example added*/
  display:none
}

.header-navigation:has(#business-plan:checked) #ameacas_oportunidades{  /*this is the example added*/
  display:none
}
```

```html
  <div class="banner-outer">
    <div class="banner-inner responsive-wrapper">
        <!-- Placeholder logo in SVG format -->
        <div class="logo-wrapper">
            <div class="white-square"></div>
            <div class="pastel-square"></div>
            <img src="logo.svg" class="logo fade-out" alt="Company Logo">
        </div>
        <!-- End of placeholder logo -->
    </div>
</div>
<header class="header-outer">
<div class="header-inner responsive-wrapper">
    <div class="header-logo">
        <img src="logo2.svg" />
    </div>
    <nav class="header-navigation">
        <a href="#missao">Plano de Negócios</a>
        <a href="#ameacas_oportunidades">Localização</a>
        <a href="#pontos_fracos">Contato</a>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>


<main>
<nav class="header-navigation">
<label class="collapse" for="about-us">Sobre nós</label>
<input id="about-us" type="radio" name="navigation" >
<div class="about-us-section">
    <!-- Content for "About Us" section with Google Maps map -->
    <!-- Replace this with your Google Maps embed code -->
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d248789.81007519642!2d-0.24168169117477634!3d51.52877184119049!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487604e9773e46e5%3A0x52963a5addd52a99!2sLondon%2C%20UK!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1647455567883!5m2!1sen!2suk" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
</div>

<label class="collapse" for="contact-us">Contato</label>
<input id="contact-us" type="radio" name="navigation">
<div class="contact-us-section">
    <!-- Content for "Contact Us" section with contact information and "Join Us" ad block -->
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Contato</h2>
        <div class="contact-info">
            <p><strong>Endereço:</strong> Rua Exemplo, 1234 - Cidade, Estado</p>
            <p><strong>Telefone:</strong> (123) 456-7890</p>
            <p><strong>Email:</strong> info@exemplo.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="join-us">
            <h3>Junte-se a nós!</h3>
            <p>Estamos sempre em busca de talentos. Envie seu currículo para careers@exemplo.com.</p>
            <!-- Replace this with your "Join Us" ad block content -->
            <img src="join-us-image.jpg" alt="Join Us Image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<label class="collapse" for="business-plan">Plano de Negócios</label>
<input id="business-plan" type="radio" name="navigation">
<div class="business-plan-section">
    <section id="missao" class="section missao">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Missão e Objetivos Estratégicos</h2>
            <p>A missão da TIME Design de Serviço é revitalizar a estrutura e a qualidade dos serviços prestados por empresas na região, melhorando as relações e a satisfação dos clientes e do ambiente de trabalho. Nossos objetivos estratégicos incluem a otimização do fluxo de informação, aprimoramento da experiência do usuário e a criação de um ambiente de trabalho mais positivo e produtivo.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="ameacas_oportunidades" class="section ameacas">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Ameaças e Oportunidades</h2>
            <p>As ameaças incluem a resistência das empresas conservadoras à mudança e a concorrência de outras empresas de consultoria. No entanto, as oportunidades são vastas, pois muitas empresas estão buscando melhorias em seus processos e estão abertas a novas abordagens que possam otimizar seus negócios, aumentar sua competitividade e oferecer soluções inovadoras e personalizadas para as necessidades específicas de cada cliente.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="pontos_fortes" class="section pontosfortes">
        <div class="content">
        <h2>Pontos Fortes</h2>
        <p>A TIME Design de Serviço destaca-se pela sua abordagem centrada no cliente e na melhoria da experiência do usuário, além da expertise de sua equipe em identificar e implementar soluções eficazes para otimizar os processos de trabalho das empresas com análise detalhada dos processos, prototipagem rápida e estratégias de melhoria do ambiente de trabalho.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section id="pontos_fracos" class="section pontosfracos">
        <div class="content">
        <h2>Pontos Fracos</h2>
        <p>Os pontos fracos incluem a necessidade de enfrentar a resistência à mudança por parte de algumas empresas e a dependência da economia regional, a possibilidade da dependência de um modelo de negócios baseado em consultoria poder limitar a capacidade de escalar rapidamente, e a possibilidade da empresa enfrentar desafios para atrair clientes em um mercado competitivo.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section id="descricao_produto" class="section descricao">
        <div class="content">
        <h2>Descrição do Produto/Serviço</h2>
        <p>O serviço que a empresa oferece é uma melhoria na estrutura de trabalho das empresas, otimizando o fluxo de informações e melhorando a experiência do usuário, não só dos clientes da empresa, por meio de melhorias na qualidade do serviço prestado, mas também melhorando a experiência do usuário que trabalha na empresa, tornando-a um lugar melhor para se trabalhar. Um período de imersão é feito pelos pesquisadores da TIME na empresa que está sendo estudada, onde cada processo de trabalho e tarefa é entendido e analisado para ver áreas de melhoria, sistemas, fluxogramas, planilhas que podem ser desenvolvidos para eles pela TIME, ciclos de informação que podem ser automatizados e assim economizar minutos, até horas e dias de trabalho. Durante essa imersão, a TIME também oferece Happy Hours para obter noções acerca das dinâmicas sociais dos funcionários, bem como para inicializar processos de melhorias na atmosfera emocional do local de trabalho.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section id="foco_negocio" class="section foco">
        <div class="content">
        <h2>Foco do Negócio</h2>
        <p>O foco da TIME Design de Serviço está em ajudar empresas de serviços a otimizar suas operações, melhorar a satisfação do cliente e criar um ambiente de trabalho mais positivo e produtivo para seus funcionários. Empresas de comércio podem ter suas operações otimizadas, mas empresas de prestação de serviços podem se beneficiar mais diretamente da carga horária de trabalho reduzida.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section id="diferenciais_produtos" class="section diferenciais">
        <div class="content">
        <h2>Diferenciais dos Produtos/Serviços</h2>
        <p>Nosso diferencial está na combinação de consultoria especializada em serviço com intervenções práticas e expertise técnica em design de serviço, com imersão detalhada nas empresas-cliente, prototipagem rápida e eventos de integração, e a oferta de soluções personalizadas e inovadoras para atender às necessidades específicas de cada cliente.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section id="estrategias_venda" class="section estrategias">
        <div class="content">
        <h2>Estratégias de Venda/Marketing</h2>
        <p>As estratégias de venda e marketing da TIME Design de Serviço serão conduzidas principalmente por meio das redes sociais e visitas direcionadas às empresas-alvo. Ofereceremos uma consulta gratuita, pesquisa e happy hour, onde a TIME desenvolverá um protótipo de solução para os desafios imediatos enfrentados pela empresa em seu pipeline de execução. Isso nos permite demonstrar o valor de nossos serviços e conquistar a confiança das empresas interessadas em melhorar suas operações.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</nav>



</main>

<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <p>&copy; 2024 TIME Design de Serviço. Todos os direitos reservados.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Notice that the <header class="header-outer"> is a sticky header that stays on top. That is the header that I want with the buttons working.

I ended up making a second one below, but it ends up not being sticky. If I place the divs and sections and elements within <header class="header-outer"> it breaks the layout

Comment: EDIT thank you for the answer! It solved it! I didn't know I could separate the buttons and the labels and separating them solved the problem I mentioned in my above comment!

Comment: Perfect I was also about to edit for a New answer. Si if it helped pls accept answer and/ or upvote